# git Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git

I met some problem when I want to set up ssh to my git. Here is the error message I got.

```
mbp-op-159:.ssh weiting.cheng$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.168.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/c/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/c/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA     16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/c/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/c/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I followed the instruction on the git hub document, but they didn't mentioned my problem.

I have private key

```
debug1: identity file /Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

I also add the key to my git hub account

git success get the my private key

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa
```

But for the unknown reason git keep going on id_dsa which I didn't generate it.

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/c/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Then I got permission denied.

anyone has suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you add your **public key** or your **private key** to GitHub?  This is *very* important; if you've done the latter, expire/destroy that key and regenerate a new private-public pair and use your public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key isn't valid. I'd recommend starting over entirely, so go ahead and delete everything in your `~/.ssh/` folder (except for `known_hosts`, you should probably keep that). Then run:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

**Use the email address associated with your GitHub account.** Be sure the key is being saved in the right user's folder. In your case the key should be saved as `/Users/c/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Finally, copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your clipboard. Go to your GitHub settings, click on the SSH Keys tab, and add the key you just copied.

I'm sure you looked at this already, but here's a [more detailed walkthrough](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).